# Pulling file from the Google Cloud server to local machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Linux n00b here having trouble pulling a file from the server to my local Windows 7 professional 64 bit machine.  I am using Wowza to stream live video and I am recording these live videos to my Google Cloud instance located here:

```
/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4
```

When I ssh:

```
gcutil --project=”myprojectname” pull “my instance”      
“/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4”  “/folder1”
```

I receive a permission denied error.  When I try saving another folder deep on my local machine i.e "/folder1/folder2" the error returned is file or directory not found.  I've checked that I have write permisions set on my local Windows 7 machine so I do not think it is a permissions error.  Again, apologize for the n00b question, I'm just been stuck here for hours.

Thx,
~Greg

Comment added 7/18:
I enter the following through ssh:

```
gcutil --project=”Myproject” pull “instance-1”        "/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4” “/content"
```

By entering this I'm expecting the file mystream.mp4 to be copied to my C:/content folder. The following is returned: Warning: Permanently added '107.178.218.8' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Enter passphrase for key '/home/Greg/.ssh/google_compute_engine':

Here I enter the passphrase and the following error is returned: /content: Permission denied Have write set up on this folder. Thanks! –  Greg

-=-=-==->

To answer the question about using Cygwin, I'm not familiar with Cygwin and I do not believe it was used in this instance.  I ran these commands through the Google Cloud SDK shell which I installed per the directions found here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/.

**What I am doing:**

After setting up my google cloud instance I open Google CLoud SDK and enter the following:

```
gcutil --service_version="v1" --project="myproject" ssh --zone="us-central1-a" "instance-1"
```

I then am prompted for a passphrase which I create and then run the following:

```
curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id -H "X-Google-Metadata-Request:True"
```

This provides the password I use to login to the Wowza live video streaming engine.  All of this works beautifully, I can stream video and record the video to the following location: /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4

Next I attempt to save the .mp4 file to my local drive and that is where I'm having issues.  I attempt to run:

```
gcutil --project=”myproject” pull “instance-1”  “/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4”  “C:/content”
```

also tried, C:/content C:\content  and C:\content

These attempts threw the following error:

**Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known**

Thanks again for your time, I know it is valuable, I really appreciate you helping out a novice.

**Update**  I believe I am close thanks to your help.  Switched to local C drive, entered the command as you displayed in your Answer update.  Now returning a new, not before seen error:

**Error: API rate limit exceeded**

I did some research on S.O. and some suggestions made were that billing is not enabled or the relevant API is not enabled and I could solve by turning on Google Compute Engine.  Billing has been enabled for a few weeks now on my project.  In terms of Google Compute Engine, below are what I believe to be the relevant items turned on:

User Info: Enabled

Compute: Read Write

Storage: Full

Task Queue: Enabled

BigQuery: Enabled

Cloud SQL: Enabled

Cloud Database: Enabled

The test video I recorded was short and small in size.  I also have not done anything else with this instance so at a loss as to why I am getting the API rate exceeded error.

I also went to the Google APIs console.  I see very limited usage reported so, again, not sure why I am exceeding the API limit.  Perhaps I do not have something set appropriately in the APIs console?

Comment: Please post the exact error message because it's unclear which permission (read, write, execute) is denied and by whom (server, client, etc.).

Comment: Thanks again Misha.  Attempted your fix.  Placed relevant information as an edit to my question.  thx.

Comment: I've updated my answer; please see below. (Note: for some reason, my comments keep being deleted, so I'm not sure if you've seen my earlier comments. Apologies for duplicates, if you see this more than once.)

Comment: I think I am oh so close thanks to your help.  Made edits to original question above. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you specifying the `--zone=[...]` flag to the `gcutil pull` command? Looks like some of your commands have it and some do not.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try [`gcloud compute copy-files`](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files). To get `gcloud`, you'll need to install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Cygwin here (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The root directory for your Cygwin installation is most likely `C:\cygwin` (see [FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.c)) and not `C:` so when you say `/content` on the command line, you're referring to `C:\cygwin\content` and not `C:\content`.

Secondly, since you're likely running as a regular user (and not root) you cannot write to `/content` so that's why you're getting the permission denied error.

**Solution:** specify the target directory as `C:/content` (or `C:\\content`) rather than `/content`.

---

**Update**: from the update to the question, you're using the Google Cloud SDK shell, not Cygwin, so the above answer does not apply. The reason you're seeing the error:

```
Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known
```

is because `gcutil` (like `ssh`) parses destinations which include `:` as having the pattern `[hostname]:[path]`. Thus, you should avoid `:` in the destination, which means we need to drop the drive spec.

In this case, the following should suffice, assuming that you're currently at a prompt that looks like `C:\...>`:

```
gcutil --project=myproject pull instance-1 /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/content/myStream.mp4 \content
```

If not, first switch to the `C:` drive by issuing the command:

```
C:
```

and then run the above command.

*Note:* I removed the quotes from the command line because you don't need it in the case where parameters don't have spaces in them.

Comment: Success!  Thank you Misha for your help.   Your instructions of switching to local C: prior to entering the gcutil pull command worked beautifully.